# Difference between local file system command touch and touchz?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I am new to Hadoop and starting working on few commands and I am trying to create a new file in linux terminal. What is the difference between

```
[prajyod@localhost ~]$touch file.txt
```

and

```
[prajyod@localhost ~]$hadoop fs -touch**z** file.txt.
```

Why in local file system for creating a new file touch is used and why in hadoop file system for creating a new file [touch**z**](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#touchz) is used

Answer (score 2):

Actually they both do the same except `touchz` is setting to a file timestamp of the folder where is created. From the source code of `touchz`:

> Creates a file of zero length at path with current time as the
>   timestamp of that path. An error is returned if the file exists with
>   non-zero length

Answer (score 0):

Both can be used for creating files. However, [`touch`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?touch) can be also used to update the modification date (timestamp) of a file.

If you also wish to update the timestamp of a file on Hadoop, you can use [setTimes](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#setTimes%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20long,%20long%29).